# How to make chat with OP?

Tags: discussion

Even though I got the privileges to create gallery chat rooms and I got rep to make chat, Unfortunately I can not make chat with the OP see the below screenshot.

[image]

I tried to avoid the extended discussion in comments, Since the OP have only 18 rep he can not make chat, but **why it not allowing me also to make chat with him** ?

Comment: It's network-wide policy, so if you want to change that you need go to meta.stackoverflow.com - anyway, rep there is tested on login to the chat system, not on entering particular room. So devs would need to rework quite a bit of it. Why did they set it up like this in the first place, I can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That user doesn't have [the privilege of talking in chat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), which requires a reputation of 20; this means that in a chat, between you and him, it would be just you who can post. This doesn't make sense, and that is the reason why you cannot create a chat room when the user doesn't have the privilege of talking in chat.

What could be done is not showing the auto-generated comment suggesting to create a chat room when one of the users doesn't have the privileges necessary to talk in chat. Already the automatic comment is not added when there are more than two users participating in the comments; users should not be confused by not seeing it.